# How to have my Text aligned at the top of its Stack if my lineLimit doesn't reach 2 in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, text, swiftui

I have created a cell that displays a received message. When a message is short and by then takes only one line, it is aligned at the center of its view, but I would have liked it at the top of if.

How can I make my text aligned at the top when the message is too short using SwiftUI without changing the size of my cell?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ConversationCell: View {
  var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 15) {
      //MARK: - Profile picture
      ProfilePictureRounded(diameter: 44)

      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack {
          //MARK: - Sender name
          Text("Steve Jobs")
            .font(.callout)
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .lineLimit(1)
          Spacer()

          //MARK: - Date of message
          Text("12/12/2012")
            .font(.footnote)
            .fontWeight(.light)
            .layoutPriority(1)
            .foregroundColor(.mainGray)
        }

        //MARK: - This is where I want my text to be aligned at the top if short
        Text("The sent message can be read here")
          .font(.subheadline)
          .fontWeight(.light)
          .lineLimit(2)
          .frame(height: 40)
          .foregroundColor(.mainGray)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: line limits 2 reached]

[image: line limit 1 align in center]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `text` modifier to the following:

```
.frame(height: 40, alignment: .top)
```